# Which component for disconnecting RS485 data signal?

Tags: circuit-design, relay

I have a situation where I'd like to be able to connect/disconnect the RS485 signal path between two PCB-mounted XLR connectors with one 3V3 output from an ESP8266.

What's the best way to achieve this? My instinct is some kind of small SPDT relay, but a lot of the ones I find online are overkill for such low voltage signals, and my instinct says that's not optimal. Is an optocoupler another option? I'm not sure whether that would work with an RS485 signal though.

Pins 2 and 3 of the NC5FAH are what need to be optional. I need to do this because a downstream device attached to the NC5FAH will auto-power off when "signal" is lost down the cable, which is what I'm trying to trigger.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What about the termination resistor(s)?

Comment: @Andyaka this is a device on a DMX line, so the termination resistor goes at the end of the chain in a connector that fits into the NC5FAH.

Comment: "a lot of the ones I find online are overkill" Why not use the ones that are not overkill?

Comment: @Alfo R1, R2 and R3 are the termination resistors I refer to.

Comment: @Andyaka Ah these are optional through hole resistors, in case the board is repurposed as a transmitter on other projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably would just use a relay. The thing about RS-485 transceivers is that the I/O are hardened and if you just use any regular analog switch or mux it won't be as hardened as the RS485 inputs.

An optocoupler output has the same issue, but on top of that an optocouplers simply won't work because RS-485 is a bidirectional bus, and optocouplers are not two-way switches.

Alternatively you could try to find out how the downstream device detects that the signal is lost.

Comment: This sounds like DMX-512 lighting control.  The controller sends a command message several times a second and devices can be set to turn off if a command message is not recieved within a specified time.

Comment: @PeterBennett If that's the case, and what qualifies as "command message not received" means no message addressed to the device rather than zero activity on the bus then the solution is easy: Simply don't send messages addressed to the device.

Comment: Unfortunately, DMX-512 sends commands for up to 512 channels in one message.  A device (light fixture) receives all messages but only pays attention to a few channels in the message - there is always bus activity to keep all devices awake.

Comment: Unfortunate indeed.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could you suggest a few parts numbers? I have only used relays that can switch mains voltage so far and these are larger and more expensive than I’m assuming I need

Comment: @Alfo Specific product recommendations are off topic but you should be searching for signal relays, not power relays. And never use them for "wet" power signals that carry significant amounts of current since that will result in arching which will leave deposits on the contacts making them ineffective for "dry" "zero-current" signals which will not be able to punch through the deposits. Signal relays will have things like precious metal contacts which are resistant to oxidization to preserve signal integrity, but as a trade off tolerance to arcing.